# Google Appscript Exporting all Sheets as PDF and name it from a specific Cell Value - Save in a specific Folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to export all sheets as PDF, get the filename from cell D5 and save them to a specific folder in Google drive, however, I'm getting a bunch of duplicates with the same name as the first sheet. Any suggestions? Also changed DriveApp.getRootFolder(); for getFolderbyName, seems that is not recognizing the actual folder, everything else in the code is working flawlessly.

```
function savePDFs( optSSId, optSheetId ) {

  var ss = (optSSId) ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(optSSId) : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  

  var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');

 
  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
  if (parents.hasNext()) {
    var folder = parents.next();
  }
  else {
    folder = DriveApp.getFolderbyName('Invoices');
  }
  

  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  

  for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    

    if (optSheetId && optSheetId !== sheet.getSheetId()) continue; 
    

    var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
        + '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId()   //the sheet's Id
        // following parameters are optional...
        + '&size=letter'      // paper size
        + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
        + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
        + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
        + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
        + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page

    var options = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      }
    }

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, options);
    
    var ss2= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    
var valor = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D5').getValue()
    
    var blob = response.getBlob().setName(valor + '.pdf');


    folder.createFile(blob);
  }
}
```

Comment: About `I'm getting a bunch of duplicates with the same name as the first sheet. Any suggestions?`, can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Sure, getting all the sheets exported as PDF with each having a different name from each sheet range D5

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I would like to confirm my understanding for your goal. I think that in your current script, only the sheet of `optSheetId` is exported as a PDF file. Your goal is that to export all sheets in the Spreadsheet as the PDF file using the sheet name to the filename. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: By all means, thank you for assisting me, the script is looping through all sheets, and exporting each one of them to PDF saving them in Drive, but I need for the script to name each PDF as the value in cell D5 of each sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to export the sheet of `optSheetId` as a PDF file.
- You want to retrieve the value from the cell "D5" of each sheet and use it to the filename of PDF file.
- You want to put the PDF file to the folder of `Invoices`. When the folder is not existing, the same folder of the Spreadsheet is used.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- For `DriveApp.getFolderbyName('Invoices')`, please modify `getFolderbyName` to `getFoldersByName`.
- In order to retrieve the value from the cell "D5" from each sheet, please modify `var valor = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D5').getValue()` to `var valor = sheet.getRange('D5').getValue();`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function savePDFs( optSSId, optSheetId ) {
  var ss = (optSSId) ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(optSSId) : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
  
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Invoices');  // Modified
  var folder = folders.hasNext() ? folders.next() : parents.next();  // Modified

  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    if (optSheetId && optSheetId !== sheet.getSheetId()) continue; 
    var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
      + '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId()   //the sheet's Id
      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=letter'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    var options = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, options);
    var valor = sheet.getRange('D5').getValue();  // Modified
    var blob = response.getBlob().setName(valor + '.pdf');
    folder.createFile(blob);
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [getFoldersByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename)
- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)

Comment: Works exactly as intended, good use of the sheet.getrange as the previous one was getting the first active sheet when the script was initiated, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Excelsson Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could understand your question by your support. Thank you, too.