# Google Sheets to pdf - combine to one pdf instead of splitting into multiple pdfs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found a script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62650714/google-appscript-exporting-all-sheets-as-pdf-and-name-it-from-a-specific-cell-va) that does everything I want however for some reason it is splitting the document into several pdf's. I would like to keep everything as it is however just create one single pdf.

Edit: My Google sheets have 5 worksheets and each worksheet at the moment becomes a seperate pdf so I end up with 5 different pdfs. I would like it to just come out as 1 pdf with 5 pages inside.

```
function savePDFs( optSSId, optSheetId ) {
  var ss = (optSSId) ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(optSSId) : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
  
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Invoices');  // Modified
  var folder = folders.hasNext() ? folders.next() : parents.next();  // Modified

  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    if (optSheetId && optSheetId !== sheet.getSheetId()) continue; 
    var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
      + '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId()   //the sheet's Id
      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=letter'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    var options = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, options);
    var valor = sheet.getRange('D5').getValue();  // Modified
    var blob = response.getBlob().setName(valor + '.pdf');
    folder.createFile(blob);
  }
}
```

Comment: Which is the format of the Google Sheet? How is it getting split, one PDF per row? or a worksheet per PDF? is it possible to provide a sample of the sheet? That would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting 5 PDF files is that, you are iterating between each page of the sheet and creating a PDF from there; instead of calling the entire sheet. I ran a test with the following code, and it exported the Google sheet as a 1 PDF.

***Note**: I made some changes to the first part of the code since I didn't have access to the other functions been call.*

I remove this part:

```
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    if (optSheetId && optSheetId !== sheet.getSheetId()) continue; 
    var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
      + '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId()   //the sheet's Id
      + '&size=letter'      // paper size
```

And modify it like this:

```
// I didn't have access to the optSSId or optSheetId so for my test I added the URL and the active sheet link to the apps script
  // you can keep this part as you had it before
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<spreadsheet_ID>/";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

  // From the URL_ext I remove  + '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId()   since we want the complete sheet
  var url_ext = '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
  + '&size=letter'      // paper size
```

So basically you form this URL:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<SPREADSHEETID>//export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&size=letter&portrait=true&fitw=true&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false&fzr=false
```

#### Update:

```
function savePDFs( optSSId, optSheetId ) {
  //var ss = (optSSId) ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(optSSId) : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
  //var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<Sheet_ID>/";
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById("<Folder_ID>");  // Modified
  //var folder = folders.hasNext() ? folders.next() : parents.next();  // Modified


  // I didn't have access to the optSSId or optSheetId so my test I added the URL and the active sheet link to the apps script
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
  + '&size=letter'      // paper size
  + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
  + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
  + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  var options = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, options);
  // var valor = sheet.getRange('D5').getValue();  // Modified
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName("test" + '.pdf');
  folders.createFile(blob);
}
```

Replace <Sheet_ID> with the ID of the Google Sheet and <Folder_ID> with the ID of the folder where the PDF file will be store.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. I seem to get this strange error message though when I try to run the script: "Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 404. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="description" content="Web word processing, spreadsheets and presentations"><meta name="viewport" c... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)" Line 25 is: var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, options); Thanks!

Comment: @Mee, I think the issue is with the URL being fetched. I do not have access to the first part of the code, so I cannot help you review it. However, I'm posting the code I use. Exactly how I did it, so you can take it as a reference. I edit the answer.

Comment: @Mee, you can also add a logger log to review what you are getting as `url + url_ext`, you can add it after `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, options);` as `Logger.log(url + url_ext);` with that information, we can review what is wrong with the code.