# Google Script Script function not found:

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this onopen and a script (which has been copied from elsewhere and modified slightly)

If I try and run it from the new menu I get:
Script function not found: savePDFs( optSSId, optSheetId ) however it did work the first time only.

If I run it using the run command in the script editor it will run but does not do anything.

Any ideas please?

Many Thanks

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Actions')
     .addItem('Make PDFs', 'savePDFs( optSSId, optSheetId )')
                .addToUi();
       };


function savePDFs( optSSId, optSheetId ) {
  var ss = (optSSId) ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(optSSId) : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
  
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('1 Service Sheet PDFs');  // Modified
  var folder = folders.hasNext() ? folders.next() : parents.next();  // Modified

  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    if (optSheetId && optSheetId !== sheet.getSheetId()) continue; 
    var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
      + '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId()   //the sheet's Id
      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=letter'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitp=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    var options = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, options);
    var valor = sheet.getRange('A4').getValue();  // Modified
    var blob = response.getBlob().setName(valor + '.pdf');
    folder.createFile(blob);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that from your script, the reason for your current issue is due to `savePDFs( optSSId, optSheetId )` of `.addItem('Make PDFs', 'savePDFs( optSSId, optSheetId )')`. Please set only the function name. It's like `.addItem('Make PDFs', 'savePDFs')` and, please modify `function savePDFs( optSSId, optSheetId ) {` to `function savePDFs( optSSId="###", optSheetId="###" ) {`. Please replace "###" with your expected values. In the current stage, the arguments cannot be set. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, Thanks for your comment. I have changed to the savePDFs but get the same error. Not sure what I should use for the ###'s. This was where I copied the script from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62650714/google-appscript-exporting-all-sheets-as-pdf-and-name-it-from-a-specific-cell-va

Comment: Thank you for replying. It seems that your showing script even when `optSSId, optSheetId` is not declared, the script works with no error. So, please modify only `.addItem('Make PDFs', 'savePDFs( optSSId, optSheetId )')` to `.addItem('Make PDFs', 'savePDFs')`.

Comment: By the way, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About `I have changed to the savePDFs but get the same error.`, I'm worried that you might have directly run the script after you modify the function `onOpen()`. In this case, it is required to run `onOpen` again. How about this?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, That works perfectly, Many thanks for your help, very good of you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, please post it as an answer. It will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think that from your script, the reason for your current issue is due to `savePDFs( optSSId, optSheetId )` of `.addItem('Make PDFs', 'savePDFs( optSSId, optSheetId )')`.

Please set only the function name. It's like `.addItem('Make PDFs', 'savePDFs')` and, please modify

> `function savePDFs( optSSId, optSheetId ) {`

to

> `function savePDFs( optSSId="###", optSheetId="###" ) {`.

Replace `###` with your expected values. In the current stage, the arguments cannot be set. Please be careful about this.

It seems that your showing script even when `optSSId`, `optSheetId` is not declared, the script works with no error. So, please modify only `.addItem('Make PDFs', 'savePDFs( optSSId, optSheetId )')` to `.addItem('Make PDFs', 'savePDFs')`